# Bind datagrid column visibility MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-3.5, wpftoolkit

.Net 3.5

I know that the columns doesn't inherit the datacontext and by reading other posts i thought this would work:

```xml
Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
                     Path=(FrameworkElement.DataContext).IsColumnNameVisible,
                     Converter={StaticResource boolToVisConverter}}"
```

However of course it doesn't..
The output window does not complain, it seems that the resource i found but the viewmodel property is newer called.

This is the entire DG :

```
<tk:DataGrid                                        
            VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"                                        
            Grid.Column="0"
            AlternationCount="2"
            AreRowDetailsFrozen="True"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            Background="Transparent"
            BorderThickness="0"
            CanUserAddRows="False"
            CanUserReorderColumns="True"
            CanUserResizeRows="False"
            GridLinesVisibility="None"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}"
            SelectionMode="Single"
            ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource columnHeaderStyle}"
            RowHeaderStyle="{StaticResource rowHeaderStyle}"
            CellStyle="{StaticResource cellStyle}"
            RowStyle="{StaticResource rowStyle}" 
            ContextMenu="{StaticResource columnHeaderContextMenu}">
    <tk:DataGrid.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="columnHeaderContextMenu" ItemsSource="{Binding ColumnHeaderContextMenuItems}" />
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        </Style>                                    
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type tk:DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        </Style>
    </tk:DataGrid.Resources>
    <tk:DataGrid.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="tk:DataGridRow.MouseDoubleClick">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource showDetailGrid}"/>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </tk:DataGrid.Triggers>
    <tk:DataGrid.Columns>
        <tk:DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="test" Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=(FrameworkElement.DataContext).IsColumnNameVisible, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisConverter}}"  />
    </tk:DataGrid.Columns>
</tk:DataGrid>
```

I have read pretty much every single solution to this problem and nothing works..

Comment: If find your question a little unclear. Are you just trying to make a data column visible or invisible depending on a bound ViewModel property?

Comment: You change your ContextMenu in `<tk:DataGrid.Resources>` - no wonder that your window DataContext isn't reachable.

Comment: @ ChrisBD : Yes that is the idea. The VM prop is set via the datacontext.

Comment: @ Felix: What do you mean? Its a contextmenu.. why would that effect the datacontext availability?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

`DataGridColumn`s are not part of visual tree so they are not connected to the data context of the `DataGrid`.

For them to **connect** together use proxy element approach like this...

1. Add a proxy `FrameworkElement` in your ancestor panel's `Resources`.
2. Host it into an invisible `ContentControl` bound to its `Content`.
3. Use this `ProxyElement` as `StaticResource` for data context source in your visibility binding.

   ```
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.Resources>
           <local:BooleanToVisibilityConverter
                  x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />

           <FrameworkElement x:Key="ProxyElement"
                             DataContext="{Binding}"/>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <ContentControl Visibility="Collapsed"
                    Content="{StaticResource ProxyElement}"/>
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn
                       Visibility="{Binding DataContext.IsTextColumnVisibile,
                                            Source={StaticResource ProxyElement},
                                            Converter={StaticResource
                                                BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
                       Binding="{Binding Text}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
   ```

Apart from `DataGridColumn`, the above approach also works great to connect `DataContext` to `Popup`s and `ContextMenu`s (i.e. any element that is not connected to the visual tree).

**Silverlight Users**

Sadly setting contents of content controls with any framework elements is not allowed in silverlight. So the workaround would be (this is just a guidance code for silverlight) ...

1. Change the framework element resource to something lightweight like a `Textblock`. (Silverlight does not allow specifying static resource of `FrameworkElement` type.)

   ```
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <TextBlock x:Key="MyTextBlock" />
   ```
2. Write an attached property to hold text block against the content control.

   ```
    <ContentControl Visibility="Collapsed" 
                    local:MyAttachedBehavior.ProxyElement="{StaticResource MyTextBlock}" />
   ```
3. In the attached dependency property changed event handler, set the bind the data context of the content control to the text block's.

   ```
     private static void OnProxyElementPropertyChanged(
         DependencyObject depObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
     {
           if (depObj is ContentControl && e.NewValue is TextBlock)
           {
               var binding = new Binding("DataContext");
               binding.Source = depObj;
               binding.Mode = OneWay;
               BindingOperations.SetBinding(
                   (TextBlock)e.NewValue, TextBlock.DataContextProperty, binding);
           }
     }
   ```

So this way the textblock may not be connected to the visual tree but will **probably** be aware of the data context changes.

Comment: Got an exeption when deselect and reselect : Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first. Do u know why?

Comment: Could be your `ContextMenu` ... it can only be attached to one parent.

Comment: Changed the ContextMenu to DataGrid CM not DGColumnHeader CM but it didn't help. I use this on multiple columns if that matters..

Comment: Does this work for silverlight as well?  FrameworkElement is in System.Windows, and I can't seem to import that as a namespace to the xaml file ...

Comment: Instead of `FrameworkElement` use any derived type like `TextBlock`. :)

Comment: The TextBlock worked no problem, but I'm getting an error at runtime, "Failed to assign to property 'System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl.Content'."
Here's the relevant code:
<Grid>...
  <Grid.Resources>
    <TextBlock x:Key="ProxyElement" DataContext="{Binding}"/>
  </Grid.Resources>
  <ContentControl Visibility="Collapsed" Content="{StaticResource ProxyElement}"/>
  <f:ScrollDataGrid> ...
<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="VIN" SortMemberPath="VIN"
  Visibility="{Binding DataContext.BasicsVisibility, Source=  {StaticResource ProxyElement}}">
Any ideas?

Comment: @John, please see my edited reply (I havent tested it though)

Comment: @AngelWPF thanks for looking into that for me!  I used this method as total workaround for now (http://mockable.blogspot.com/2010/10/databinding-visibility-of-silverlight.html) but I'd prefer not having to extend base classes for simple functionality so I'll go back and try out yours once I can.

Comment: For some reason this only works for the Visibility column, although I don't understand why. For example, binding "Width" has no effect at all. Binding "DisplayIndex" throws an exception, telling me -1 is out of range - even though its correct in the binding.

Comment: @WPF-it can you explain plz why `ContentControl` is required here if we use `ProxyElement` anyway? [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073740/binding-visibility-for-datagridcolumn-in-wpf) solution uses the similiar approach, but no `ContentControl` is required.

Comment: @monstr, Freezable classes hack the `DataContext` ... in our case 'proxyelement' is not Freezable, so the only way it can acquire a `DataContext` if it is hosted within the `VisualTree` which is possible if it is a `Content` of a `ContentControl`. Also for the second solution in your link, the `NameScoping` is not resolved in `Template` like `DataGridColumnHeaderTemplate` so the `ElementName` wouldn't work. The solution I have provided takes care of both situations.

Comment: Hi WPF-it, your approach works perfectly fine and I am able to hide/show column MVVM way. However when I hide column, an extra blank column is shown at the end. I have AutoGenerateColumns set to False & HeaderVisibility set to Column. All column widths are set to Auto (* doesn't help). Do you have any solution/inputs for the extra column? Thanks

Comment: I made the mistake to think that DataBindings of Visibility (at DataGridColumn) be a subset of items which bound as ItemsSource in the DataGrid. <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding... has nothing to do with the binding of Visibility in DataGridColumn. The binding of Visibility in DataGridColumn, is bound to the DataContext (indicated f.e. by a ProxyBinding)

Comment: Thank you a thousand times, this works! I spent good part of the day on this. I hate anyone who created WPF and introduced this kind of bugs practically unsolvable without Google and SO. Once again I have to state that WPF as a technology is only good for writing tutorials, I can't imagine that anyone use it for production apps voluntarily.