# Binding with ElementName does not work

Tags: wpf, binding

Here is the XAML:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="0"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Columns}"
              x:Name="ColumnsGrid" RowHeaderWidth="0">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=Header}" 
                                Header="{Binding ElementName=ColumnsGrid, Path=DataContext.Count, StringFormat=Columns ({0}), diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>  
    </DataGrid>
```

Binding returns error: System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element.

What do I miss?

**Update:**

Here is the answer:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2008/11/22/forwarding-the-datagrid-s-datacontext-to-its-columns.aspx

> What is happening here?     The Columns collection is just a property
>   in the Datagrid; this collection is not in the logical (or visual)
>   tree, therefore the DataContext is not being inherited, which leads to
>   there being nothing to bind to.

**Update 2:**
Good article about DataGrid's caveats: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2009/04/07/5-random-gotchas-with-the-wpf-datagrid.aspx

Comment: I don't think `ElementName` works *within* the same element.

Comment: Here is the answer:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2008/11/22/forwarding-the-datagrid-s-datacontext-to-its-columns.aspx

> What is happening here?     The Columns collection is just a property
> in the Datagrid; this collection is not in the logical (or visual)
> tree, therefore the DataContext is not being inherited, which leads to
> there being nothing to bind to.

Comment: yet another funny bug that proves the only thing WPF is good for is writing tutorials, this technology is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding on `DataGridColumn` for `Header` abd `Visibility` properties needs special treatment...

See this...

[Bind datagrid column visibility MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7711275/bind-datagrid-column-visibility-mvvm/7711611#7711611)

Comment: Yep this worked for me too. `ProxyElement` approach is a very good hack. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in the Count property of the object that is referred to in the DataContext you try and use regular databinding:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="0"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Columns}"
          x:Name="ColumnsGrid" RowHeaderWidth="0">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=Header}" 
                            Header="{Binding Path=Count, StringFormat=Columns ({0}), diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>  
</DataGrid>
```

**EDIT**

Apparently [the columns of a datagrid are not part of the Visual Tree](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2008/11/22/forwarding-the-datagrid-s-datacontext-to-its-columns.aspx) 
So using ElementName and RelativeSource will not work.
Perhaps you should add the property to the object the column is bound to.

Comment: I need the DataContext of DataGrid.

Comment: @voroninp - Did you try RelativeSource Ancestor?

Comment: @voroninp - I added to my answer