# WPF - DataGrid - Hiding DataGridCeckBoxColumn via DataTrigger

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datatrigger

I've got a DataGrid in wpf with different columns. I want to change the property "Visibility" of one explicit column via datatrigger, but a cant access the "Style" property.

How can i collapse or hide the hole column?

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding IsChanged, Mode=OneWay}"
                            Header="Changed" 
                            CanUserSort="False">
    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>

    <!--more columns-->
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: Finally I found my solution here:
[Bind datagrid column visibility MVVM][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7711275/bind-datagrid-column-visibility-mvvm

Answer (score 1):

`DataGridRow` and `DataGridCell` have Styles, `DataGridColumn` doesn't. I'm guessing this is because rows and cells are the only things being *displayed* in the UI. Columns are only used by `DataGrid` internally to keep track of its rows and cells and their content.

Conveniently, columns do have a `Visibility` property though, which you can bind on each specific column:

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Visibility="{Binding ...}"
                        ...
```