# Failed Binding Fontsize of label which is put in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I want to change the Fontsize of a lable which is put in the DataGrid like this

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTextColumn>
              <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                   <Label Name="LabelInGrid" Content="{DynamicResource LabelNameIn}" FontSize="{Binding ContentFontSize}"/>
              </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
         </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
<Label Name="LabelOutGrid" Content="{DynamicResource LabelNameOut}" FontSize="{Binding ContentFontSize}"/>
```

If I change the value of ContentFontSize. The FontSize of LabelOutGrid will change,But LabelInGrid out of works

Comment: I believe the DataGrid has some ItemsSource, am I right?

Comment: Yes DataGrid has band some ItemsSources

Comment: If the collection bound to the ItemsSource is an ObservableCollection, try explicitly calling the CollectionChanged event. This should force the DataGrid to be rendered again, with updated font size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should see some binding errors in your Visual Studio output window when you run this application. That is because it is trying to find the bound `ContentFontSize` property on the `Label` object, not on your actual `DataContext`.

Change your `Label` element to something like this:

```
<Label Name="LabelInGrid" Content="Header" 
       FontSize="{Binding DataContext.ContentFontSize, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
```

Or

```
<Label Name="LabelInGrid" Content="Header" 
       DataContext="{Binding DataContext,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"
       FontSize="{Binding ContentFontSize}"/>
```

[DataGridColumns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtextcolumn(v=vs.110).aspx) are not `FrameworkElement`s so they do not inherit the parent's DataContext, so you have to use `RelativeSource` binding to get to the parent's DataContext.

There are other ways to achieve this: 1) Using a [DataBinding proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7711611/587690) 2) [Forwarding](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jaimer/2008/11/22/forwarding-the-datagrids-datacontext-to-its-columns/) DataGrid's DataContext to DataGridColumns whenever DataGrid's DataContext is changed.